# Press brake tooling for 360 tube?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, design, steel, industrial-engineering

I’m trying to find out if it’s possibly to form a cylinder or tube with a diameter of 1 inch using some kind of curling die for a press brake. I’ve seen dies that make small 360 degree bends like that but they always have additional length of sheet metal extending from the tubular section. Does anyone know if it’s possible to form just a small tube without additional material extending out? This tubing would be used for handles to lift something, similar to a handle bar on a bicycle or something.

Comment: An image showing what you expect the finished handle to look like will help to offer the best answer and the most optimized process. The currently accepted answer only explains how tubing is made, and not how a finished handle would be produced. Do you want to make tubing or tubular handles?

Comment: I’m only concerned about forming the tune shape using a press brake. Anything after that (welding/bending/etc) isn’t an issue

Comment: It's relevant in that we'd decide how to remove the mandrel, and the shape of the tooling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only seen it done on a continuous basis  . Flat stock is pulled through a few dies then final rollers press the two edges together to make a weld ( usually an ERW , electric resistance weld ). Most steel pipe up to about 24" diameter is made this way. Small tubing , like 1 ", is made that way. But some small tubing is made by starting with 4 " pipe and cold drawing down to the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

To make handles (where liquid won't be flowing through the tube) simply crush tubing in a press. It's called tube flattening.

[image: Flattening Press]

[image: Flattening Press Results]

[image: Flattening Press]

[image: Flattening Press]

[image: Crush Tubing]

Notice that the tubing is simply crushed to bend it into a handle shape using a press.

Comment: No.. I need to make tubing from sheet metal using a press brake

Comment: Do you want it welded closed? Also, is there any value in leaving this answer; I'm willing to delete it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do - the process called "bumping". You can see how it works - with the backgauge of the press brake you push the metal and perform a lot of bends.

This is the process to make light poles in industry. You will never get small diameters as 1 inch.